# column "new" of relation "publications" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I want to develop a trigger that updates a trigger after an insert or update.

I follow this [tutorial](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2006/aug/04/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/) and created a function that is called by the trigger after an insertion. I tried with both after and before.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS answer_update_question_timestamp ON public.publications;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_update_question_timestamp()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$
BEGIN
    UPDATE publications SET new.last_edit_date = now() WHERE publicationid = new.publicationid;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER answer_update_question_timestamp AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON publications
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_update_question_timestamp();




CREATE TABLE publications
(
    publicationid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    body VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL ,
    creation_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    last_edit_date TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT body_length CHECK (CHAR_LENGTH(body) >= 10 AND CHAR_LENGTH(body) <= 1000),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_publications_users"
        FOREIGN KEY ("userid") REFERENCES users ("userid") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I noticed that NEW doesn't work with operations such as `FOR EACH STATEMENT` but I haven't found anything wrong with `FOR EACH ROW`

Does anyone kno what I'm doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: you return `null` instead on `new`?..

Comment: you should create first `creat table publications` script.!

Comment: The correct syntax is just `NEW.last_edit_date := now(); RETURN NEW;` here (and use a `BEFORE` trigger). Don't update the table, which caused the trigger to fire: it will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: not to mention `last_edit_date default now()` would give exactly same with much less effort

Comment: @VaoTsun I had `RETURN NEW;` and nothing happened. I don't think the source of my error is that

Comment: "Don't update the table, which caused the trigger to fire: it will cause an infinite loop." I didn't understand this, sorry @pozs

Comment: @LuísCosta your trigger listens on `UPDATE`s of `publications` while it issues an `UPDATE` on `publications` itself, which will trigger itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want last_edit_date to be set to now() on insert or delete, just set default to now():

```
CREATE TABLE publications
(
 ...
    last_edit_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
....
);
```

If you still want to go there,instead of updating itself and returning null assign a new value to NEW:

```
NEW.last_edit_date := now(); 
RETURN NEW;
```

Endless loop pozs is talking about happens when you **assign a function that updates a table to a trigger on that table that fires on update**

**Update** - working example for OP:

```
t=# CREATE TABLE publications
(
    publicationid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    body VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL ,
    creation_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    userid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    last_edit_date TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE TABLE
t=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_update_question_timestamp()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$
BEGIN
    new.last_edit_date := now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# CREATE TRIGGER answer_update_question_timestamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON publications
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_update_question_timestamp();
CREATE TRIGGER
t=# insert into publications select 1,'2',now(),3,null;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from publications;
 publicationid | body |       creation_date        | userid |       last_edit_date
---------------+------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------
             1 | 2    | 2017-03-30 15:28:10.897846 |      3 | 2017-03-30 15:28:10.897846
(1 row)
```

Comment: Oh great! I was really confusing myself and being redundant . Thanks!